# Change icon size in unity's application switcher (alt-tab)?

Tags: unity, application-switcher

When I switch applications with alt-tab under Unity (full version, not the 2d one), my open applications are displayed, represented by their respective icon. These icons are quite huge... everytime I hit alt-tab I'm a bit surprised by the thing that pops in my screen. I'd prefer a much smaller icon size.. is there a way to change this somewhere?

They seem to be ~96x96, I'd aim for 48x48 :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that's possible. However, you can install compiz-settings-manager and attempt to use another application switcher -- there are three or so options available. However, I did not see any that would allow small icons.

Comment: Ended up enabling the old application switcher from ccsm (changed shortcuts for the unity one so they don't conflict). It doesn't really allow me to change the size of icons, but it does feel much snappier. Also, it doesn't group windows (HAH!)