# Can I increase the size of the preview in Gnome's Application Switcher (alt+tab)?

Tags: gnome

Similar to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/181856/change-icon-size-in-unitys-application-switcher-alt-tab) but for Gnome 3 - is there a way to increase the size of the preview in the Alt+Tab application switcher?

Answer (score 2):

Without editing source code, one cannot customize the preview size of the default Alt+Tab window switcher. However, you could try well maintained Gnome Shell extension [Coverflow Alt-Tab](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/97/coverflow-alt-tab/) by p91paul. It provides an alternative Alt+Tab switcher showing large previews.